# Self Hosted Web API and Web Server sharing a domain

Tags: reverse-proxy, self-hosting, asp.net-web-api2

I have a self-hosted Web API (`ASP.NET Web API`). Now let's assume I would like to deploy it on a machine which already has a web server running. In order to share a domain, do I have to use a reverse proxy? I would prefer NOT to change anything on the existing installation!

At the end I would like to see:

```
www.example.com/ThisIsAnExistingWebSite 

www.example.com/api/ThisWouldBeMyWebAPI
```

Comment: Use `mod_rewrite` and make the path `/api/...` point to a different machine. Or yet better, use a subdomain `api.example.com`. What webserver and system is the existing site running on?

Comment: The existing site runs on IIS.